# PHP Image upload failed in middle. Half image uploaded

Tags: java, php, android, image, yii

How can I detect if an image has been uploaded completely or partially? I encountered a strange situation where only half an image has been uploaded. The following image was uploaded by a user through an Android application via a Web service:

[image]

The admin portal and Web service is written using the Yii framework.  What might have caused an image to be created like this? Android Developer sends the base-64 encoded string and I decode it the following way:

```
$profilePicture = $data['profilePicture'];
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $rnd = sprintf('%04d', rand(0, 9999));
    $fileName = $rnd . '_' . time() . '.png'; // random number + timestamp

    $uploadPath = User::getProfilePicturePath() . $id;

    if (!file_exists($uploadPath) and ! is_dir($uploadPath)) //create a directory only if it does not exist.
        mkdir($uploadPath);

    if (!file_put_contents($uploadPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, base64_decode($profilePicture)))
```

I doubt this is the cause, because Android Developer is sending the base-64 encode before file is completely uploaded. Or is it something else?

**$profilePicture is equal to 64 base string like this,**

```
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
```

Android side code is as below,

```
String imageString = Base64.encodeBytes(byteImage);
```

This is the class file used.

http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/issues/secure/attachment/10313/Base64.java

Comment: look into size of uploade and original image

Comment: verify by file size / md5 checksum maybe ?

Comment: what's md5 checksum ? can you tell what could be causing this ?

Comment: @diva i want to handle it from server end, not client.  from client side what i am getting is 64 base json encode string. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: post your code server end

Comment: @diva the code posted above is the server code.  $profilePicture contains 64 base string.

Comment: i have checked your encoded value in here.http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html so may be have problem with encoding.if you can upload base64 encode in android may be we can give help.

Comment: try multipart upload, post android code also

Comment: @diva Please check the android code. I have posted it.

Comment: I think you have problem with base64 class.Why you have used other base64 class.Android will support default base 64 encode.If you have bitmap image it is easily can convert it to base64 encode string.

Comment: @Sajith4U could you please share with me a code block that does it the way you are explaining without using 64 base class. ?

Comment: @fireclaw48 i have posted my answer.check that this will work.after encoding this way make sure get the encoded string and decoded using online tool to check encoding works fine.

Comment: if my answer is correct make it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `imagecreatefrompng` function to check if provided image is broken or not.

```
$src1 = 'F:\Test\0374_1423730003.png';
$src2 = 'F:\Test\5030_1423722865.png'; // broken

$im = @imagecreatefrompng($src1);
if ($im)
    echo 'created img';
else
    echo 'not created, broken image';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);

        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();

        String temp=null;

        try{

            System.gc();

            temp= Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){

            baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50, baos);
            b=baos.toByteArray();

            temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            Log.e("EWN", "Out of memory error catched");

        }

        return temp;

    }
```

This method helps you to convert Bitmap image to Base64 encode string.